# Changing a global variable inside a function when using "tee"?

Tags: bash, shell

I would like change the value of a global variable.
It's working perfect when I execute the function normally.
But it's not when I execute it with a tee.
I need the tee in order to have both output on the screen and on the file.

Why the Tee causes this behavior ?
Is there a way to modify the global variable within the function with Tee ?

```
FCT_main()
{
MY_VAR=2
}

MY_VAR=1

echo "MY_VAR=$MY_VAR"   # -> print 1.
FCT_main | tee file.out
echo "MY_VAR=$MY_VAR"   # -> print 1, but I expect 2 !

echo "\n"

echo "MY_VAR=$MY_VAR"   # -> print 1.
FCT_main
echo "MY_VAR=$MY_VAR"   # -> print 2 as expected.
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not with `tee`. It's with pipe operation.
Each command in a pipe is executed in separate subshells.

So any changes made to the variables in functions are not reflected.

You can do the following process substitution, but still its not equivalent to piping.

```
FCT_main > >( tee file.out )
```

**Note**:Process substitution works only with some shells. This code was found working with bash shell.

Entire code

```
FCT_main()
{
MY_VAR=2
}

MY_VAR=1

echo "MY_VAR=$MY_VAR"   # -> print 1.
FCT_main > >( tee file.out )
echo "MY_VAR=$MY_VAR"   # -> print 1, but I expect 2 !

echo "\n"

echo "MY_VAR=$MY_VAR"   # -> print 1.
FCT_main
echo "MY_VAR=$MY_VAR"   # -> print 2 as expected.
```

Comment: Thanks yor the explanation.

I tried your other way but I get a syntax error :

`code./test.sh[10]: syntax error at line 10 : (' unexpected`

Comment: @Sephi I've added the entire code to the answer. try copy paste it as it is and execute.

Comment: Ok i get it, it's working fine on Linux but sadly I'm using SunOS :(

Comment: @Sephi which shell are you using `echo $SHELL`and your os version `uname -a`?

Comment: Using Korn Shell (ksh). OS version is SunOS 5.10 Generic_147441-27 i86pc i386

Comment: @Sephi some versions of ksh does not support "process substitution" \, which is the name of the above used technique. I thought it was bash shell coz u've tagged bash.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem occurs in the following snippet:

```
i=0
cat $file | while read line; do
    i=$(($i + 1))
done
```

`i` will be 0 at the end of the loop.

```
i=0
while read line; do
    i=$(($i + 1))
done < $file
```

will actually work. The problem is that `while` is executed in a subshell (and so is `cat` for that matter) when used in a pipe-line, but not when redirecting stdin.

If you post the actual code we might be able to help you devise a solution to your specific snippet.